# Cannot install the software because of version of mysql-server issue

Tags: mysql

When I install git. It showed the error as following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
git-all : Depends: git-doc but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-el but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-arch but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-cvs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-svn but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-email but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-gui but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gitweb but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: git-daemon-run but it is not going to be installed or
                   git-daemon-sysvinit but it is not going to be installed
mysql-server-5.5 : Breaks: mysql-server (< 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks.